# C++11: any easier way of template class method inline declaration?

Tags: templates, c++11, inline

**This question builds up on my**:

[C++ library: .hpp + .inl (separate definitions and declarations) vs .hpp only (in-class body code)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18064948/c-library-hpp-inl-separate-definitions-and-declarations-vs-hpp-only-i)

**Moving templated functions into inline files is definitely an official hell.** See below three examples. From my OLD neat way of doing things (#0), to a really expanded way (#1), to a more compacted way (#2) to the imaginary dream pipe way (#3).

```
// #0 the actual class definition
namespace CA {
    template <typename tnChar>
    class MyClass {
    public:
        typedef tnChar                      tChar;
        typedef std::basic_string<tChar>    tString;
        MyClass(); // {}
        tString Method1(const tString& aParam) const; // { return aParam; }
    };
};
```

This is the inline **version #1**. It has both namespace and class.

```
template <typename tnChar>
CA::MyClass<tnChar>::MyClass(){}

template <typename tnChar>
typename CA::MyClass<tnChar>::tString
CA::MyClass<tnChar>::Method1(const tString& aParam) const {
    return aParam;
}

template <> // specializing
typename CA::MyClass<wchar_t>::tString
CA::MyClass<wchar_t>::Method1(const tString& aParam) const {
    return aParam;
}
```

This is the inline **version #2**. It is wrapped in namespace. Saved from adding the `CA::`.

```
namespace CA {
    template <typename tnChar>
    MyClass<tnChar>::MyClass(){}

    template <typename tnChar>
    typename MyClass<tnChar>::tString
    MyClass<tnChar>::Method1(const tString& aParam) const {
        return aParam;
    }

    template <> // specializing
    typename MyClass<wchar_t>::tString
    MyClass<wchar_t>::Method1(const tString& aParam) const {
        return aParam;
    }
}
```

This is the inline **version #3**. It is wrapped in namespace and class. Saved from adding the `template <...>` ... `CA::MyClass`. **IMAGINARY version**. Not possible but desirable!

```
#if 0 // like this is ever gonna work
// inline version #3 (IMAGINARY)
// wrapped in namespace and in class
// 'inline class' should make this functionality happen in C++my
namespace CA {
    template <typename tnChar>
    inline class MyClass { // :)
        MyClass(){}

        tString Method1(const tString& aParam) const {
            return aParam;
        }
    };

    template <>
    inline class MyClass<wchar_t> { // :) - too much imagination
        tString Method1(const tString& aParam) const {
            return aParam;
        }
    };
}
#endif // disabled
```

My question is: **Is anything like version 3 even remotely possible?** Without having to `typename` the return values and write the `template <...>` each and every single time. I know the reasons why we need to do this, but I'm wondering if the new `C++11` or the next `C++14` has any plans to address *template class inline method grouping*?

*Having the `inline class` keywords trigger the imaginary functionality in #3 would be mind blowing and it would make externalizing template class methods so easy... and logic... and grouped... and short :)*

Comment: Will the `auto` keyword do this?  I *think* I've seen `auto` on return types, but I might be mistaken.

Comment: @Aggieboy `MSVC` is kind of slow in catching up with things... `auto` returns... not yet! And don't think it applies here.

Comment: @Aggieboy An interesting hint, the trailing-return-type is indeed in the scope of the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the risk of stating the obvious, that syntax is available when declaring member functions inside the class body. If your religion requires you to put the member functions in a separate `.inl` file, you could include that file inside the class body itself.